# Prevent webpage zoom/resize in IE on Windows 8 snapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am design a responsive layout webpage
I use jquery to update divs according to the change in window width
But when you snap IE modern ui to one side of the screen, it zooms out on the page making everything smaller, and this is totally screwing up the display of the page.
How can I stop IE from changing the zoom level on snap?

Comment: you better use bootstrap.js for making a complete responsive design very easily. refer this link http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, wrote too soon.
the answer for me is this...

```
@media screen {
    @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
}
```